# Is there a way to setup code generation in JOOQ for multiple schemas with the same table structure?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jooq, flyway, jooq-codegen-maven

We have a multi-tenant database, where each tenant has their own dedicated schema. The schemas always have identical table structures. What I'm trying to figure out is if there's a way to pass the schema to JOOQ at query time when using code generation to track the schema. Something like:

```
dslContext.useSchema("schema1").select(A.id).from(A).fetch()
```

It seems like the schema is always tied to the table object and the only option for mapping at runtime is statically via an input schema and an output schema.

Environmental info: Java/Kotlin, Maven, Spring Boot, Postgres, Flyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features you are looking for are:

- [Code generation time schema mapping](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-catalog-and-schema-mapping/)
- [Runtime schema mapping](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-render-mapping/)

See also the [`FAQ`](https://www.jooq.org/faq)

The simplest solution here is to just turn off the generation of schema information in the code generator:

```xml
<outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>
```

Or at runtime

```java
new Settings().withRenderSchema(false);
```